# Add multiple member - score values not supported in Redis Booksleeve

Tags: c#, redis, booksleeve

I'm trying to store multiple member-score values using Redis Booksleeve but the Booksleeve api doesn't seem to support this functionality.

**conn.SortedSets.Add** overload supports only single pairs of value - scores.

Do i miss something or this is on purpose or something that you forgot to implement?

Currently i'm updating my sorted set in a transaction loop like this:

```cs
foreach (ForumMessage message in messages)
{
    trans.SortedSets.Add(db, redisKey, message.id.ToString(), message.id);
}
trans.Execute();
```

Is the above the same as doing a ZADD with multiple member-score values from performance perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be *quite* as efficient:

- it'll send the command and key multiple times
- there is a good chance of emptying the output buffer repeatedly, which can cause packet fragmentation

But... it'll still be pretty fast.

There are hacky ways around the latter, including:

- batching
- suspend/resume flush (be **very** careful to use `try`/`finally` if you do this!)

However, you might want to know that [StackExchange.Redis](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/so-i-went-and-wrote-another-redis-client.html) has a multi key/value `SortedSetAdd` method that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks I'try batching although the above code is included inside a transaction. Is batching necessary when I use transactions.

Comment: @PanKak if you are using transactions, then indeed that is a form of batching - the second issue (packet fragmentation) should bot be an issue

Comment: Anyway I'm surprised with the new client, it looks quite promising. You just ruined my tognight's sleep actually :) I'll try it ASAP!!!